# history.push redirect overrides the the path I set to different one

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I have this widget

[image]

the whole thing is clickable to a certain path. I put two buttons inside it, edit and remove

remove is working properly it execute a saga. now edit button I want it to be a link that redirects to certain URL. and I cannot do it because I cannot put `<a>` inside a `<a>`. React shows me a warning.

so I used a button that redirects using :

1.

```
import {Link, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
    <button onClick = {() => history.push(`/domain/${props.domain.id}/edit`)}>
    edit
    =</button>
```

2. Because I use connected-react-router, I also tried

   `import {history} from '../../../redux/store'; <button onClick = {() => history.push(`/domain/${props.domain.id}/edit`)}`

They both have the same behaviour:
[image]

[image]

As you can the redirect is overriden with '/domain/5f95554624aa9a0006351825' which is the link of the outer link.

Even if I changed the url to something like '/users' it still gets overriden.

I just want to to redirect the user to simple URL. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop `Link`'s default behavior.

```
<Link to="/xyz">
  Link
  <button
    onClick={(e) => {
      history.push(`/domain/${props.domain.id}/edit`)
      e.preventDefault()
    }}
  >
    edit
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much.